# How to make react-window FixedSizeList scroll with the viewport instead of the component's scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-window

I am trying to integrate `react-window`'s `FixedSizeList` and `FixedSizeGrid` components to increase the initial rendering speed of my page. Is there some way for me to let the user scroll down the `react-window` component using the viewport's scrolling area? I was also
wondering if there is some way to remove the scrollbar from the `react-window` component and only use the viewport's scrolling as I described above.

I tried integrating the documentation version of `FixedSizeList` into my page and as you can see, since the total height of all my rows is greater than the height I specified in the component so the vertical scrollbar beside the component appears, which I want to remove. I also cannot figure out how to let scrolling downwards on the viewport make the `react-window` component scroll down the rest of its rows.

From looking online, I think I might need to modify the CSS style of the `FixedSizeList` to have `overflow:hidden` to remove the scrollbar but how can I ensure that I keep the scrolling functionality and that the user can scroll down the component from anywhere in the viewport?

[Current version with no react-window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMj2m.jpg)

[FixedSizeList version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubg93.png)

```
  const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
    <div style={style}>Row {index}</div>
  );

  <FixedSizeList
      height={500}
      itemCount={38}
      itemSize={35}
      width={"100%"}
    >
      {Row}
  </FixedSizeList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a package linked from the [react-window github page](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) called [react-virtualized-auto-sizer](https://npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized-auto-sizer). It is also made by bvaughn and is a good solution to the problem.

This solves the issue by allowing you to set the height of your `FixedSizedList` to the height of its content, so it does not get a scrollbar. Here's how that would look:

```
  <AutoSizer>
    {({ height, width }) => (
      <FixedSizeList
        className="List"
        height={height}
        itemCount={1000}
        itemSize={35}
        width={width}
      >
        {Row}
      </FixedSizeList>
    )}
  </AutoSizer>
```

Here's a full example on codesandbox: [image: Edit compassionate-keldysh-nsrkw0]

Comment: This solution works! but the user will scroll without any reference of the list scroll itself only the main scroll will be the reference and it isn't accurate. it could be confusing for the user :(

Comment: @napstercake did you find solution to this problem?